# Testing one Cucumber feature takes minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, spork

I've got the following gems installed for testing:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'spork'
gem "factory_girl_rails"
gem "capybara"
gem "guard-rspec"
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

All my tests take *forever* to run - testing one feature with Cucumber takes a good two minutes, and this is with Spork running with nearly everything in prefork.

The test itself took 0.544s on the last run, but it seems to be running cron.rake, rakefile, and I don't know what else. I checked these two files and they don't seem to have anything significant going on. Do you have any pointers for how I can improve this situation?

The readout:

```
San-iMac:app san$ rake cucumber features/user_sessions.feature
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3
Running cron.rake
begin Rakefile
/Users/san/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3
Feature: User Sessions
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Rake is the problem. Try running cucumber directly instead, with "bundle exec cucumber" if you are using Bundler, or just "cucumber".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows? We've noticed it takes much longer to spin up cucumber on windows than linux or mac.

I appreciate it might not be that easy to switch, but it'll typically save a couple of minutes per spin up.